# How to stop jQuery function execution after one time

Tags: jquery

i need you help. I have running a function when `key=13` is hit, And the function is calling ajax, but after that the ajax function does not stop, it is working all the time, so i need to know how can i stop it after one time. Some code here:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('articletext', {
            toolbar: [
                {name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'RemoveFormat']},
                {name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates']}, // Defines toolbar group with name (used to create voice label) and items in 3 subgroups.
                ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'], // Defines toolbar group without name. 

            ]
        });            

        editor.on("key", function(event) {
            //alert(event.data.keyCode);
        if (event.data.keyCode===13)
        {                
            this.document.on("keyup", ck_jq);

        }                   
        });

    });

function ck_jq()
    {
        var charsCount = CKEDITOR.instances['articletext'].getData().replace(/<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/gi, '').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        var wordCount = CKEDITOR.instances['articletext'].getData().replace(/[^\w ]/g, "").split(/\s+/);

        var max = <?php echo $orderInfo->wordstarget; ?>;

        var txtVal = $('#title').val(); //title field value
        var descVal = $('#description').val();//description field value

        var wordstitle = txtVal.trim().replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length;//words in title
        var wordsdesc = txtVal.trim().replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length;//words in description

        var text = CKEDITOR.instances['articletext'].getData();
        var valueOfText = text + txtVal + descVal;//add all fields text to one

        var wordsCountAll = wordCount.length + wordstitle + wordsdesc;//add all fields words to text
        xajax_checkKeywords(valueOfText, <?php echo $base_url[3]; ?>, wordsCountAll);           

    }
```

So i need to stop the `function ck_jq();` after one time execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you registering a event handler to document, that is the problem because once the handler is registered any whenever any key pressed in the document the function gets called the registered handler in this case `ck_jq` gets called.

```
editor.on("key", function(event) {
    //alert(event.data.keyCode);
    if (event.data.keyCode===13)
    {                
        ck_jq()
    }                   
});
```

Comment: I cant detect "Enter" key in another way, that is the only thing that worked for me. I'm not good in jquery. :(

Answer (score 1):

don't bind the function on `this.document.on("keyup", ck_jq);`

this will work every time `keyup` on document.

and multiple times this function will be binded many times and will create an infinite loop

```
if (event.data.keyCode===13){                
        ck_jq();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Next time i will know about it. Thanks!